# HP ScanJet 4070 Photosmart produces just stripes after OS upgrade

Tags: macos, scanning

My HP Scanjet 4070 stoped working after an upgrade to the current MacOS. It scans the pictures but then the saved PDF only contains stripes:

[image]

This happens on two machines. What can I do?

I asked in the HP support forum. They sent me on to another support forum and in the second forum nobody cared.

Comment: We care! just give us bit more details, does it work when scanning at scanner (not from Mac), current as 10.9.4 ? how is it connected to your mac?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly well with an old macbook pro that has not been updated. The scanner is connected via USB. Scanning itself seems to work well. I can see the scanned figures. But there seems to be a problem with the export. Some scanners have protections against scanning money or similar things one should not scan. Maybe it is a bug in this stuff. In any case it seems to be a software problem related to the update.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Did you try scanning without using HP drivers? Like from Preview?  Or using the Image Capture app on your Mac?

Comment: This is very strange. The scanner works, but neither preview nor image capture sees it. I tried both USB ports. Nothing ...

Comment: yes it is strange, so let us look in to how your Mac identifies the scanner in the About this Mac, and what driver does it use. While at it please also publish your current HP scanner settings or look at this for reference https://uknowit.uwgb.edu/page.php?id=26412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From HP forums:](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Mac-Printing-and-Scanning/HP-Scanjet-4070-and-Maverick/td-p/3088471)

> The ScanJet 4070 software will not be updated to work with Mac OS
>   10.9.
>
> You might be able to successfully connect to the scanner but using the
>   HP Scan software results in file saving errors or all gray output.
>
> You might try a third party solution like [VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com/).
>
> You will need to install the HP Software and 10.8 patch first....

It costs $40 -- $80 depending on your choice.

You can still try and [download this driver](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL907), but I doubt it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am really disappointed that HP leaves their customers in the dark. I am glad that VueScan works. I hope my printers will not stop working one day and make me buy VuePrint =;-).